# Should we send it to [jupyter]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

There is a tag [jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jupyter) and a tag [jupyter-notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jupyter-notebook). Is this on purpose? If so, what's the difference? Shouldn't we burninate one of them?

Comment: Thanks for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid only mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. Flag/vote/edit/retag the posts after consensus is reached. For more info, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: I'm only familiar with ipython, the predecessor of jupyter. You can have ipython, the interactive shell, and you can have ipython notebooks, the interactive web stuff, resembling Mathematica notebooks. I can imagine that jupyter has the same distinction: interactive shell vs fully fledged published page with interactive components. (Not answering, as I'm only guessing that it's similar for jupyter.)

Comment: @AndrasDeak yes that distinction is pretty spot on. The only extra I'd note is that Jupyter has grown beyond Python-land and now supports a large number of different languages using the same system (might not affect the discussion, but just an FYI for context on the differences).

Answer (score 20):

I'm only familiar with [ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipython) vs [ipython-notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipython-notebook), but since [Jupyter is a spin-off of IPython](http://jupyter.org/about.html) (extended with a lot of features, as well as languages beyond **Pyt**hon such as **Ju**lia and **R**), the situation is similar (as also verified by the [comment of @Ffisegydd](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323167/should-we-send-it-to-jupyter?noredirect=1#comment344903_323167)).

[jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jupyter), as a whole, stands for the entire project, which contains among other things an interactive shell, and a web-based interactive document format (/application?) called the Jupyter Notebook. [jupyter-notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jupyter-notebook) corresponds specifically to questions related to Jupyter Notebooks.

This means that [jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jupyter) is a proper superset of [jupyter-notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jupyter-notebook). It makes sense to keep [jupyter-notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jupyter-notebook) as an individual tag, as the many components of Jupyter might require further distinction beyond [jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jupyter). But as there are other components of [jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jupyter) than notebooks, it also makes sense to keep the broader tag too.

So in my opinion, both tags should be kept.

Comment: There are definitely features of notebooks that you cannot have in the console, and so having a way to distinguish them may be reasonable.

Comment: So, what are the questions that should have this tag?

Comment: @Braiam, questions about the qtconsole could e.g. be tagged with jupyter, but not notebook - if that's the question.

Comment: @cel example please, remember tags cannot exist without questions.

Comment: did I misunderstand you here? I thought the question is: Does it make sense to have `jupyter` and `jupyter-notebook` as separate tags. How does searching for a concrete example on stackoverflow help in the discussion? Jupyter is designed the way @Andras Deak described. I don't see how adding an example question can help. I can try to find docs/talk of the developers that confirms exactly what @Andras Deak described here.

Comment: @cel if you believe the tags should exist at all, there *must* be questions that should have them, otherwise, how we should know which *should not* have them?

Comment: @Braiam I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183272/how-do-i-access-objects-in-user-namespace-with-jupyter-client) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154860/import-error-no-module-named-jupyter-cms) should only be tagged [jupyter] (these were in the front 25 questions of the tag). And of course essentially all the [jupyter-notebook] questions should be tagged with that.

Comment: @Braiam An *analogy* to what you are saying: "I noticed that there is a [tag:c++] and also [tag:c++-standard-library]. We should burninate one of them".  The fact that the standard library is a subset of c++ doesn't imply the tag shouldn't exist, and the fact that a lot of question about c++ involve using the standard library in some way doesn't mean we can get rid of the c++ tag. The same is with jupyter. Jupyter is **much** more than the notebook. A clear example of question you are asking would be something about implementing custom kernels for jupyter (I bet there are already out there)

Comment: @Bakuriu what? You just lost what I'm saying. I'm asking for examples where the tag is applied correctly. Just because something *exists* doesn't mean that it should have a tag. Questions about the topic has to exist first on SO, for a tag to be created about it. So your analogy is not only wrong, but totally irrelevant.

Comment: @Braiam, `Questions about the topic has to exist first on SO, for a tag to be created about it.` - This is not about creating new tags...

Comment: @cel why not? Is a perfectly good reasoning. If there are no posts that need the tag, because others fit better, the tag has no purpose.