# Flag declined - so is it OK for a chat room to post same canned comments on every single post in a tag?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, moderation

For the tag [burninate-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request) , a certain chat room posts a robotic canned comment for every-single-post-in-the-tag.

Is it appropiate for a chat room to do so? Can it go mass commenting promoting their chat room on all posts for a tag of their choice?

As per my understanding, an OP who has 100k or so rep does not need a canned comment about editing tips. Also, other chat rooms who associate themselves with tags such as JS, Python or Android don't post canned comments on **every single post** tagged JS, Python or Android. So it this acceptable for meta-tags?

The users involved in this activity claim to understand the rules of moderation, does it mean that moderators have provided consent for mass commenting to their room only?

I flagged for mods using a custom flag to clean up the canned comments for this tag, but it was declined. I would like to understand why this flag was declined?

Comment: Clickbaity title is clickbaity.

Comment: FWIW, the canned comment isn't usually for the OP, but for others reading the burnination request.

Comment: Related: [Evaluation of SOCVR's Burnination Process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323121/evaluation-of-socvrs-burnination-process)

Comment: Is this a new "valid usage" of comments @ryanyuyu. I ask because the same Meta audience reads these comments again and again and again. If we don't like reading the same "require comment for downvote" feature-request every week, do we like to read the same comment every day on MSO?

Comment: @Sunshine so your objection to the comment is based on the fact you believe they are promoting their chat room?

Comment: There's been a problem with non-Meta goers, usually of <2k rep, mass-editing a tag out of questions before the burnination has been approved, Sunshine. The comment is an attempt to discourage this, as one of the goals of burnination is to clean up the questions in the tag while we're at it. If someone's _just_ editing out the tags, then 1) they make it harder to find and clean these questions and 2) they're not improving the posts as they should be. A lot of these edits are robo-approved, if they're suggested, making this even harder to deal with.

Comment: Yes @psubsee2003. It is promotional.

Comment: I'm not the member of SOCVR, but what I get when reading that comment is that SOCVR has taken a responsibility in keeping the process works. There's no feeling of promotion (as in, marketing, or spamming).

Comment: So is mass commenting the solution @Kendra?

Comment: @Sunshine While this process is being vetted and altered, the comment pointing to the chat room is being used to let people know of the process. I imagine once the process in the post ryanyuyu linked is done and the "faq-proposed" post is made, any comments will be posted there instead. Until SE gives us a better way to combat these mass edits, commenting on each new burnination request is the best there is. (Note: I'm not part of the chat room, but I am a very active meta goer so I've seen this all unfold.)

Comment: Don't get me wrong- I'd prefer a better solution to this issue than mass commenting, but it's all we have for the moment. For example, a process like [what's requested in this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319914/automatically-append-guidance-to-questions-tagged-burninate-request) would be much better in my mind. The system would automatically warn about mass editing and, when there is a faq, can point to the faq.

Comment: @Kendra Quick note - The canned comment doesn't point to the chatroom (why would it?), it points to a GitHub page maintained by Room Owners and a few regulars that explains the process. There isn't even a direct link to the room in that page, but there's a link to the transcript at the end for a noteworthy related message from a moderator, who agreed to help out.

Comment: @Kendra Shog's post which "defines the process" doesn't mention mass commenting...

Comment: @Kyll Thanks, I hadn't actually checked. The question mentioned the comment was "promoting the chat" so I had guessed the link went there. I see even less issue with the comment if the link doesn't even _go_ to the chat room and just mentions it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I declined that flag because I saw no reason to delete the comment, simple as that. [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323350/lets-put-an-end-to-this-or-an-s#comment345746_323350) is the comment in question:

> Thanks for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid only mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. Flag/vote/edit/retag the posts after consensus is reached. For more info, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

In a quick query, I see this canned comment being used 15 times on Meta, all in response to tag removal requests. Looking over these, I saw that many of them had been upvoted many times:

- [Should we send it to [jupyter]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323167/should-we-send-it-to-jupyter#comment344870_323167)
- [I've done some [research] and I found a tag that needs to go](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323081/ive-done-some-research-and-i-found-a-tag-that-needs-to-go#comment344431_323081)
- [Filter out the [google-analytics-filters] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323358/filter-out-the-google-analytics-filters-tag#comment345786_323358)
- [Can we start burninating or synonymising [initalization]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322823/can-we-start-burninating-or-synonymising-initalization#comment342924_322823)
- [The [setstyle] tag should go out of style](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322728/the-setstyle-tag-should-go-out-of-style#comment342485_322728)
- [Burninate [custom-lists]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322308/burninate-custom-lists#comment340224_322308)

and none of those had been flagged. It seemed that people found the comments useful, so I saw no need to wipe all of these.

I don't know that you can leap to the conclusion that by declining to delete a single comment moderators are officially endorsing these. I just saw no reason to delete this one or to remove relevant canned comments that people had upvoted elsewhere. We don't wipe upvoted canned comments that point out common PHP or regex issues, for example.

Comment: Or even system generated auto comments from the VLQ reviews and possible duplicates.

Comment: I made the leap because I mentioned in the flag that every post of the tag had this comment, and asked for cleanup. And it was declined. Thanks for the response, Brad. Shog's post about burnination process does not mention mass commenting, so I wanted to know if it was endorsed later.

Comment: Thanks for posting this acknowledgement of such comments being legitimate and allowing the community to keep informing readers about details of burnination process :)

Comment: Finally endorsed by a mod @gnat :-)

Answer (score 10):

<sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>Thank you for giving the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) yet another podium.</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

Let me explain a bit how it came this far, as Brad already [answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323378/578411) why he declined the flag.

As you might or might not know and like or might not like the [Stack Overflow Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room is a chat room that has moderation as its main topic. This means that users who both feel comfortable and have the privileges to edit, flag or handle the close vote queue among others gather in that room so they can have some fun and/or ask for opinion on the best call to action. We strive to clean-up the mess that is left behind when others moved on.

One of the tasks that this community is faced with are the requests to burninate tags. As this is a typical moderation effort requiring voting, flagging and editing it is not strange that these requests get the attention of our room. We simply set out on a mission to clean the questions in a certain tag, either on request (for example, we cleaned a lot of "looking for a tool" questions and the [legal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295117/this-tag-should-not-be-legal) request) or because we try to help in [formalizing and organizing](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md) the handling of those requests a bit.

As our regulars are frequenting both the queues and meta we are also aware of good willing users with less than 2K rep, that start, probably triggered by seeing a burninate request, a re-tag spree.  This annoys reviewers, is a useless waste of effort and sometimes needs moderator time to either fix or even suspend users from reviewing.

In our effort to prevent such mishaps we decided to add another canned, robotic as you wish, [auto-comment to our collection](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments/blob/master/sites/meta.stackoverflow.com/questions.md). As the number of incoming burninate requests is rather low (only 17 in the last 30 days) we have a feed in our room so we can leave the comment as soon as the question is posted.

I only learned today that more people dislike those comments, something I didn't notice earlier, except a textual improvement.
You and Quill suggested in chat that most of the comment should be moved to the tag-wiki. That is something we have already done [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info). The users with more English finesse have taken-on the challenge to make the comment less robotic. If nothing works we will add [*By the way, nice pants*](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4925561#4925561). I expect that once the burnination process has its faq-proposed as I suggest [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323121/evaluation-of-socvrs-burnination-process) the comment can simply refer to that and doesn't need the reference to SOCVR in the comment.

So I thank you for the great feedback, both here and in chat. Remember that I'm a flower, I smell a bit but I don't bite.

**Tl;dr** - the comment emerged as a reaction on several incidents with burnination retags. The comment should serve as a precaution for visitors of burnination request. If the meta-crowd feels they rather deal with the incidents or have a better idea, we're happy to stop posting the noise all together.

Comment: Thanks for the response Rene. I brought it here as you said. Keep up the good work. I will ignore this tag for now.

Comment: I'll ping you if we burninate a tag you're familiar with @Sunshine Thanks for your feedback, much appreciated.